# Legality of manual counterattacks vs counterattacks executed autonomously by a self-defense bot

Tags: united-states, internet

There is a new twist on the [DDOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Distributed_DoS) (distributed denial-of-service) attack vector which has been used for taking down servers on the internet.

This newest version sends data packets targeting [memcached software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached) that is utilized on many servers.

Now an article in thehackernews.com describes a possible solution to this form of attack. Paragrah 5 in the article `'Kill Switch' to Mitigate Memcached DDoS Attacks — Flush 'Em All` (available [here](https://thehackernews.com/2018/03/prevent-memcached-ddos.html)) says that

> However, the good news is that researchers from Corero Network
>   Security found a technique using which DDoS victims can send back a
>   simple command, i.e., "shutdown\r\n", or "flush_all\r\n", in a loop to
>   the attacking Memcached servers in order to prevent amplification.

This solution would essentially amount to sending commands back to the server that is attacking your server.

I have a couple of questions I would like to ask about this:

1. Are there laws in USA against attacking a server that is attacking
   your servers?
2. If such laws exist, do they include attacks executed by humans or
   would it be legal for a "self-defense" bot to autonomously undertake
   such attack?

Comment: I suspect that 18 U.S.C. § 1030 would be applied here, even in the case of self-defense. However, I couldn't find any specific examples of the CFAA being applied to a case like this, much less the outcome of such a case.

Comment: I believe there were talks about creating "hack back" laws which allowed entities to attack in self defense. https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/10/13/us_hack_back_law/